# How to improve this code snippet in imperative way?

Tags: java, arraylist, functional-programming

The code snippet below has accessing global variable side affect, how can I improve this code snippet?

```
    double total = 0;
    for (Student s : myStudentList){
        total = total + s.getSchScore();
    }
    System.out.println(total + " is total marks.");
```

Comment: `double total = myStudentList.stream().mapToDouble(Student::getStudentMark).sum();`

Comment: Also, [the use of raw types is highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it#:~:text=A%20%22raw%20type%22%20is%20the,were%20updated%20to%20use%20generics.) (`ArrayList myStudentList = new ArrayList();` -> `ArrayList<Student> myStudentList = new ArrayList<>();`). Otherwise, using the stream API will involve at least a type cast and possibly an additional filter step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing/able to type the list (`ArrayList<Student> myStudentList = new ArrayList<>();`) a possible solution woudl be

```
final double total = myStudentList.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Studen::getScore)
    .sum();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HgDfKo)

If you must/want to continue with the raw type list (which is [highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it#:%7E:text=A%20%22raw%20type%22%20is%20the,were%20updated%20to%20use%20generics.)), then I would recommend two additional steps: filter out all non-`Student`-objects and cast the objects to `Student`:

```
final double total = ((List<?>) myStudentList).stream()
    .filter(o -> o instanceof Student)
    .map(o -> (Student) o)
    .mapToDouble(Studen::getScore)
    .sum();
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2PYa3U)

Answer (score 0):

Using raw types is strongly discouraged, as it requires casting each Object to the required type.

```
final double total = myStudentList.stream().mapToDouble(x -> ((Student) x).getStudentMark()).sum();
```

If the `List` was declared with `Student` as the type parameter, the code would be much improved.

```
List<Student> myStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
//...
final double total = myStudentList.stream().mapToDouble(Student::getStudentMark).sum();
```